# Red Hat: Back-Off time during failed authentication attempts

Tags: rhel, authentication, pam, wait

I am searching for a way to configure some sort of back-off or wait time during failed authentication attempts. The idea is that after each failed authentication attempt, the user has to wait an increasing amount of time:

```
1. attempt > 5s back-off time > 2. attempts > 10s back-off time > 3. attempts > 15s back-off time > 4. attempt > user blocked
```

I was having a look at Red Hat's [security guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/pdf/security_guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Security_Guide-en-US.pdf) and various PAM modules  but couldn't find a suitable parameter.

Does anybody know how to configure such a feature?

Comment: Are we talking local authentication (like `sudo`) or remote authentication (`ssh`) here?

Comment: Local authentication primarily. But I would be interested in remote solutions as well.

Comment: A remote solution would be `fail2ban`